# Using MySQL "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" with the Joomla database connection object

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, mysql, jdatabase

In a Joomla 3 component I use the MySQL "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" command to import large CSV files into a Joomla database table.

When moving to a new server, it is no longer possible to configure MySQL via php.ini like this:

`mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`

The web host suggests to use this PHP command:

`mysqli_options($mysqli, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);`

What I would like to achieve is to be able to do this with the Joomla database connection object.

A) Adding a $options parameter to the JConfig object in Joomla's configuration.php did not work:

`public $options = array('local_infile' => true);  // <-- ??`

B) Alternatively, I tried creating another database connection like this:

```
$option['driver']   = 'mysqli'; // Database driver name
$option['host']     = 'host';   // Database host name
$option['user']     = 'user';   // User for database authentication
$option['password'] = 'pass';   // Password for database authentication
$option['database'] = 'name';   // Database name
$option['prefix']   = 'xxx_';   // Database prefix (may be empty)

$option['option']   = array('local_infile' => true); // <-- ???

$db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($option);
```

Experimentation with replacing local_infile with allow_local_infile, mysqli.local_infile, or MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE does not seem to work either.

Will this even be possible with Joomla?
Is there any other best practice for importing large CSV files into a Joomla database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to include the more detailed example based on the 1st comment.**

I have been able to get the follow statement to work, or at least not fail, in a simple Joomla 3 Model;

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
if ($db->getconnection() instanceof mysqli)
{
    mysqli_options($db->getConnection(), MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
}
```

However I haven't look too hard into how to confirm that it has made the required change in the MySQL connection so you will need to do that with your function.

Comment: I have tried to convert this to Joomla 3 like this - but this did not work either:

```$connection = $db->getConnection();
if ($connection instanceof JDatabaseMySQLi) 
{
    $mysqliConnection = $connection->getDriver()->getConnection();
    mysqli_options($mysqliConnection, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
}```

Comment: I have updated the answer to show a working example as per your comment above.

Comment: FYI: In one of my queries, it seems to be working and is loading the CSV data correctly, but is still throwing the error. - Currently I do not see any side effects.

Comment: On Joomla 4 the driver seems to load correctly, but I get this error message if I run my LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ... SQL with this code in an try catch block: 

'$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->execute();'

This is the error message:
`This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Any ideas?

Comment: You might like to open a new question with the message you are now getting and include what is held in $sql. You can refer/link back to this question for context.

Comment: I opened a new question here [link](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33232/mysql-load-data-local-infile-with-database-connection-object-in-joomla-4)