# MySQL "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" with database connection object in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, mysql, database, jdatabase

In order to import large CSV files into a Joomla database table, I use the MySQL "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" command as follows:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $path . "' INTO TABLE " . $db->quoteName('#__mytable') . " ";
$sql .= "CHARACTER SET LATIN1 ";
$sql .= "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ";
$sql .= "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
$sql .= "IGNORE 1 LINES ";
$sql .= "(id, name, ...);";

try {
   if ($db->getConnection() instanceof mysqli) {
      mysqli_options($db->getConnection(), MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
   }
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $msg = $e->getMessage(); 
   $code = $e->getCode();
}

try {
   $db->setQuery($sql);
   $result = $db->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $msg = $e->getMessage(); 
   $code = $e->getCode();
}
```

This works fine in Joomla 3 [- as described in this thread](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33151/using-mysql-load-data-local-infile-with-the-joomla-database-connection-object):

In Joomla 4, the 2nd try/catch throws the following error:

`error 1295 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Is there a way to get this code to work in Joomla 4 as well?

Comment: After the setQuery() and before the execute() insert these two lines to dump the actual SQL that is about to be executed.
`$fred = $db->query->dump();
echo '<pre>'. $fred . '</pre>';`
This might show you if there is some other statement or syntax that is not valid with MySQL being added as part of Joomla 4

Comment: If you haven't already found it, this question has similarities to your statements, less the obvious PREPARE statement, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360756/mysql-load-data-this-command-is-not-supported-in-the-prepared-statement-protoco but it might be a useful reference.

Comment: Thanks for the hints: I do get a 500 error on $db->query->dump() which stops execution of the PHP script.
No feedback from the Webhosting company, yet. Cannot make changes on Server or MySQL. Still looking for a way to fix this on PHP / Joomla side.

Comment: Are you using an IDE or XDebug with this code that you can step through what is going on? I can't think why the dump() would be causing a 500 error.

Comment: Well, I tried a lot. The code breaks on $db->setQuery($sql). Switched to local development environment. Still get the same error message: `1295 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Comment: Is it breaking on the setQuery() or the dump()? Your previous answer says it was breaking on the dump()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 4.0, Joomla database layer always uses prepared statements. And as the error states, the query you're trying to run is not supported when used in prepared statements. This is true at least for the combination of the MySQLi library and the MySQL database used. To get things working, you might have to not use prepared statements. You can do that by bypassing Joomla database layer completely and manually creating a mysqli instance. You can also use `Joomla\Database\DatabaseInterface::getConnection()` to get the mysqli instance, as you are already doing, and run the query directly on it:

```
$connection = $db->getConnection();
mysqli_options($connection, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);

// Replace #__ table prefix.
$sql = $db->replacePrefix($sql);

// Run the query.
$connection->query($sql);
```

PDO, on the other hand, appears to work correctly (YMMV). However, `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` attribute must to be passed to the constructor of PDO class and cannot be set later. Therefore, you need to create a new driver instance with the attribute already in:

```
$options = [
    'host' => 'host',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database',
    'prefix' => 'xxx_',
    // Set connection attributes.
    'driverOptions' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1],
];

// Create PDO MySQL driver.
$db = (new Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory)->getDriver('mysql', $options);

// Execute the query.
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: With the first variant I get `1295 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`.

Comment: In the second I added `'driver' => 'mysqli',` to the options array. Using `'driverOptions' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1]` I get `1295 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet` as well. Change it to `'options' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1]` the error message is `[0] HY000, 2068, LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check related settings like mysqli.allow_local_infile|mysqli.local_infile_directory or PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE|PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't removed the old query execution code. Can't say without seeing complete code. I don't know why you're trying to change the provided options.

Comment: I tried the provides options, too. But it didn't work and the error message stays the same.

Comment: I need to see the complete code. Calling `query()` method on mysqli object should not be producing the error since it does not use prepared statements.

Comment: Finally it worked. Looks like I had to get rid of the comma in the $options array. In my setup I had to add the mysqli driver, too. So finally it looks like this:  
`$options = [
     'driver' => 'mysqli',
     'host' => 'host',
     'user' => 'user',
     'password' => 'pass',
     'database' => 'database',
     'prefix' => 'xxx_',
     'driverOptions' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1]
];`

Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: That's very confusing. `driver` key in options array is not used by the provided code so you should not need it. The driver is instead passed as the first argument to `DatabaseFactory::getDriver()`. And it should be `mysql`, not `mysqli` anyways.

Comment: I tested this successfully without the driver setting in the $options array. Thanks for the hint and explanation.