# Joomla 4 db prepared statement re-write

Tags: joomla-4.x, migration

I am migrating a componenet from J3 > J4.
I am stuck with some db code (not my strongest).

Maybe there is a kind soul that could re-write this code so it works with J4 and i could onwords :-)

```
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS " . $db->qn('redSHOP_Column_Update');

    $db->setQuery($query)->execute();

    $query = "CREATE PROCEDURE " . $db->qn("redSHOP_Column_Update") . "(
        IN " . $db->qn('tableName') . " VARCHAR(50),
        IN " . $db->qn('columnName') . " VARCHAR(50),
        IN " . $db->qn('newColumnName') . " VARCHAR(50),
        IN " . $db->qn('columnDetail') . " VARCHAR(255)
        )
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        COMMENT " . $db->quote(
            'Procedure for use in redSHOP to update / add column to table avoid unexpected errors.'
        ) . "
        BEGIN
            SET tableName = REPLACE(tableName, " . $db->quote('#__') . ", " . $db->quote(
            JFactory::getConfig()->get('dbprefix')
        ) . ") ;
            SET columnDetail = REPLACE(columnDetail, " . $db->quote('#__') . ", " . $db->quote(
            JFactory::getConfig()->get('dbprefix')
        ) . ") ;
            set @ColOldExist = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME=columnName AND TABLE_NAME=tableName AND table_schema = DATABASE());
            set @ColNewExist = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME=newColumnName AND TABLE_NAME=tableName AND table_schema = DATABASE());
            IF (@ColOldExist = 0 AND @ColNewExist = 0) THEN
                /* Both column doesn't exist. Just add column */

                set @StatementToExecute = concat('ALTER TABLE `',DATABASE(),'`.`',tableName,'` ADD COLUMN `',newColumnName,'` ',columnDetail);
                prepare DynamicStatement from @StatementToExecute ;
                execute DynamicStatement ;
                deallocate prepare DynamicStatement ;
            ELSEIF (@ColOldExist = 1 AND @ColNewExist = 0) THEN
                /* Old column exist. New column not exist. Change column */

                set @StatementToExecute = concat('ALTER TABLE `',DATABASE(),'`.`',tableName,'` CHANGE `',columnName,'` ','`',newColumnName,'` ',columnDetail);
                prepare DynamicStatement from @StatementToExecute ;
                execute DynamicStatement ;
                deallocate prepare DynamicStatement ;
            ELSEIF (@ColOldExist = 0 AND @ColNewExist = 1) THEN
                    /* Old column not exist. New column exist. Update column */

                    set @StatementToExecute = concat('ALTER TABLE `',DATABASE(),'`.`',tableName,'` CHANGE `',newColumnName,'` ','`',newColumnName,'` ',columnDetail);
                    prepare DynamicStatement from @StatementToExecute ;
                    execute DynamicStatement ;
                    deallocate prepare DynamicStatement ;
            ELSE
                /* Old column exist. New column exist. */

                IF (columnName <> newColumnName) THEN
                    /* Old column is different with new column and both exist => The old column had to be remove */

                    set @StatementToExecute = concat('ALTER TABLE `',DATABASE(),'`.`',tableName,'` DROP COLUMN `',columnName,'`');
                    prepare DynamicStatement from @StatementToExecute ;
                    execute DynamicStatement ;
                    deallocate prepare DynamicStatement ;
                END IF ;
                
                /* Update structure of new column column */

                set @StatementToExecute = concat('ALTER TABLE `',DATABASE(),'`.`',tableName,'` CHANGE `',newColumnName,'` ','`',newColumnName,'` ',columnDetail);
                prepare DynamicStatement from @StatementToExecute ;
                execute DynamicStatement ;
                deallocate prepare DynamicStatement ;
            END IF;
        END";

    $db->setQuery($query)->execute();
```

Comment: Don't think this is going to work on MySQLi using prepared statements. You can try not using prepared statements or using PDO. See similar case https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/33234/12652.